# Fopen Permission denied

Tags: php, iis

Tento ler um arquivo `TXT` na rede, porém o `PHP` sempre retorna erro de permissão.
A pasta está compartilhada e consigo vê-la pela rede `windows`.

Uso servidor `Windows` com `IIS7`.

No `xampp` local consigo acessar esses arquivos via `php` normal.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ponteiro = fopen ("//192.168.1.2\DADOSTXT\arquivo.TXT","r") or die("ERRO");

while(!feof($ponteiro)){
  $linha = fgets($ponteiro,4096);
  echo $linha."<br>";
}

fclose ($ponteiro);
```

Alguma ajuda ?

Comment: você vai ter que dar permissão para o Apache ler esse arquivo na rede, vê se isso ajuda: http://phpbrasil.com/phorum/read.php?11,163196.
Se conseguir, compartilhe. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns detalhes a serem corrigidos:

1. Ao invés de `//192.168.1.2\` você deve usar `\\192.168.1.2\`
2. Você deve "escapar" o caractere `\` deixando ele assim `\\\\192.168.1.2\\DADOSTXT\\arquivo.TXT`

### network/domain account

Se isto não resolver o problema será necessário usar uma conta de network/domain para o Apache conseguir acesso:

1. Abra o menu Iniciar -> Executar (ou WindowKey+R) e digite `services.msc` em seguida pressione "Enter".
2. Procure o serviço Apache (ou wampapache)
3. Clique com o botão direito neste serviço e selecione "Propriedades".
4. Vá até a aba "LogOn".
5. Selecione o "botão radio" aonde está escrito "Está conta:", os campos irão ficar habilitados então entre com as credenciais para que que você necessita que o apache tenha acesso. Se for uma conta de dominio/network use a syntax `DOMAIN\nome-do-usuario` (ou use a busca para encontrar a conta usando o botão "Procurar...")
6. Clique em OK e reinicie o serviço do Apache (acaso for o wamp reinicie pelo próprio wamp).
7. Para verificar se as alterações funcionaram vá até o TaskManager (gerenciador de tarefas ou <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) e veja se qual nome de usuário aparece junto ao processo do Apache (httpd.exe)